# Having a nightmare with AS3 classes and using them

Tags: actionscript-3, class, reference, instantiation

I really thought I understood the whole AS3 class thing but I have been having a major problem with the most simple of tasks and it is killing me!

Basically, I have my Document Class and am trying to create an object of another class. Both files are in the same folder.

I am currently using:

```
var sForest:simpleForest = new simpleForest();
```

In the hope of referencing a class that has this code (I took out everything it does and it still has the same problem):

```
package ActionScript  
{
public class simpleForest {

    public function simpleForest() {
        trace ("hi!");
    }
}
}
```

And I keep getting these errors:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: simpleForest.

1048: Method cannot be used as a constructor.

I know I am missing something small and stupid but I can't figure it out at all!

Comment: As a best practice, classes should be capitalized and packages camel-cased.

Comment: Are both files in a folder called ActionScript?

Comment: Hi! I capatalized the class name to "SimpleForest" and now it works, I realised I had a function with the same name - stupid me! Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @Way You may submit that as an answer to your own question if it was the solution.